# Passing props in Next.JS from class component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can someone advise on how can I pass my this.state as props from a Class component to a Functional component.
I moved my app from React.JS to Next.JS. Previously, I used React-Router-DOM with  and  components and everything was fine:

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/favorites"
               render={() => (<Favorites favorites={favorites}
               clickedRemove={this.removeFavoritesHandler}/>)}/>
        <Route path="/"
               render={() => (<Search
               submitted={this.submitHandler}
               changed={this.searchHandler}
               query={query}
               videos={videos}
               clickedAdd={this.addFavoritesHandler}
               clickedRemove={this.removeFavoritesHandler}/>)}/>
    </Switch>
```

All these things I'm getting from

```
state = {
    favorites: [],
    videos: [],
    currentChannel: {},
    query: "",
};
```

But with moving all the data to Next.js  component stopped to load, saying the props are undefined

```
import React from "react";

import Video from "./video";

const Favorites = ({ favorites, clickedRemove }) => {
    return (
        <div className="videos">
            {favorites.length !== 0 ? (
                favorites.map((video) => {
                    return (
                        <Video
                            key={video.broadcast_id}
                            {...video}
                            clickedRemove={clickedRemove}
                        />
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <div style={{ width: "100vw", marginTop: "2rem" }}>
                    Fetched videos will appear here :)
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Favorites;
```

Comment: I'd recommend you have a read through [Migrating from React Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to find an answer there, but couldn't extract anything valuable for my case. Maybe, it's better for me to check the State Management process, in order not to pass any props between components